# Switching from maven build to tomcat server

Tags: maven, tomcat

Currently I use maven commands in CMD to build my project. It is quite time consuming as it needs to build the entire project even when there are very few java changes.
Is there any plugin or solution available that I can make use of Apache Tomcat to build my maven project.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: You can use maven plugins to deploy on tomcat, I mean you can copy de generated artifact on Tomcat webapps dir to update app (maybe it will need to execute some script to restart server after changes). Tomcat is a servlet container, not a compiler so you cannot use Tomcat server to build apps.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more natural to use maven to build _and_ deploy to tomcat?